# aws command not found in docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

After successful installation of awscli in my alpine box, when I try to run it, it says it can't find the `aws` command. even I have included aws installed path in $PATH.
This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.6
RUN apk -v --update add \
        python3 \
        py-pip \
        groff \
        less \
        mailcap \
        curl \
        && \
    pip install --upgrade awscli==1.14.5 s3cmd==2.0.1 python-magic boto3 pyyaml && \
    apk -v --purge del py-pip && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/*
WORKDIR /project
COPY wait-for-localstack.sh .
RUN chmod 755 wait-for-localstack.sh
RUN ls -ltr
COPY test_cf_create_or_update.py .
ENV PATH="/usr/bin/:$PATH"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
CMD ["./wait-for-localstack.sh", "http://localhost:4566",  "python3", "test_cf_create_or_update.py"]
```

and wait-for-localstack.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

which aws

until aws --region eu-west-1 --endpoint-url="$host" s3 mb s3://mytestbucket;
do
  >&2 echo "S3 is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

sleep 30

>&2 echo "localstack is up - executing command"
echo "hello world"
exec $cmd
```

Now after the build, if I run it's complaining that `aws: not found`
even though aws is installed in `/usr/bin/aws`

Comment: PATH should point to directories, not binaries.

Comment: sorry about that, It was a typo, even though it still says the same.